# Building SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql

I need some help to build SQL Query. I have table having data like:

```
ID   Date         Value
 1   12/01/2009     4
 2   12/02/2009     3
 3   12/03/2009     6
 4   12/01/2008     2
 5   12/02/2008     4
 6   12/03/2008     5
```

Here is my query:

```
select ID, Date, Value from MyTable
where Date between '12/01/2009' and '12/04/2009'
```

and it returns the following rows:

```
ID   Date         Value
 1   12/01/2009     4
 2   12/02/2009     3
 3   12/03/2009     6
```

But I need the data in the following format:

```
ID   Date         Value   lastYearValueANDSameDate
 1   12/01/2009     4                2
 2   12/02/2009     3                4
 3   12/03/2009     6                8
```

Here I need to get the last year value of the same date in the `lastYearValueANDSameDate` column.

Thanks

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956588/table-design-sql-question/1956631#1956631). it's the same problem in a different database. adapt to your situation.

Comment: The requirements listed are not quite complete, and the sample data set does not answer the unknown questions.  It appears you want entries of lowest ID joined with entries of next higher ID on the right.  Is that correct?

Comment: @NickLarson; plz check now, I have edit my question. have you got my requiment now?

Comment: @Muhummad, I cleaned up the formatting and added (what I think is) your full query (always a good idea including the full one since there may be other clauses in there which change behaviour). Please check that the query is correct and fix if not.

Comment: @Paxdiable; yes, right, the issue is resolved by Astander answer, I also try your answer, it gives me the result but not 100% and Astander answer give me 100% result what I want.. Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Date DATETIME,
        Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, '12/01/2009', 4
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, '12/02/2009', 3
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3, '12/03/2009', 6
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4, '12/01/2008', 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5, '12/02/2008', 4
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 6, '12/03/2008', 5

SELECT  t.ID,
        t.Date,
        t.Value,
        tPrev.Value
FROM    @Table t LEFT JOIN
        @Table tPrev ON DATEADD(yy, -1, t.Date) = tPrev.Date
WHERE   t.Date between '12/01/2009' AND '12/04/2009'
```

Comment: @Astander; That's grate answer, I hope this will work for me, let me check first. Thanks

Comment: @Astander, I send you an email, I need some help in query. Plz reply. Thanks

Comment: Have you placed the query in SO yet, I will have a look when I can ASAP X-)

Answer (score 1):

Untested but I think it will work:

```
select a.id, a.date, a.value, b.value
from mytable a, mytable b
where a.date >= '12/01/2009'
and   a.date <= '12/04/2009'
and   a.date = dateadd(year,1,b.date)
```

Keep in mind that this is a Cartesian product (albeit not a full cross-join due to the last `and` clause) so it will not produce rows for dates that do not have corresponding last-year rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
ID INT,
Date DATETIME,
Value INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, '12/01/2009', 4
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, '12/02/2009', 3
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3, '12/03/2009', 6
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4, '12/01/2008', 2
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5, '12/02/2008', 4
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 6, '12/03/2008', 5


SELECT *,(SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM @Table WHERE Date=DATEADD(YEAR,-1, a.Date)) AS last FROM @Table a

WHERE a.Date between '12/01/2009' AND '12/04/2009'
```